# Undefined offset: 0 in

Tags: php

Don't know much about php, but I can figure somethings out and copy and paste.
My webhost seems to have updated php and code that worked for years now throws up errors. I had someone develop my php connection to a filemaker database and he is no longer available to help me with this problem:

The problem occurs in two places:

```
> Undefined offset: 0 in
```

this is the code:

```
$resultData = $Result['data'][$DataKeys[0]];
// and here: 
$aRecID = preg_split('[.]',$DataKeys[0]);
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($DataKeys)` or `print_r($DataKeys)`

Answer (score 2):

It means `$DataKeys[0]` does not exist.
Try a `var_dump` on `$DataKeys` and simply take a look what is inside.

Use this small helper function, it generates a better output:

```
function pr($var) {
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($var);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```